# C program taking forever when creating array and writing to .txt file

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a random array of integers from 0-31 for a 256 x 256 array. The code works as I can do it for smaller arrays really well. However, when trying to create the 256x256 array and write it out to a .txt file it is taking forever to run. I'm new to C so any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated. thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MaxC 256
#define MaxL 256

 int main(){

 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("arrays256.txt","w+");
     int c[257] = {0};
     int i=0,j=0,r;
     int n[MaxC][MaxL] = {{0}};

     //int* n = (int*)malloc(MaxC * MaxL * sizeof(int));
     srand(time(NULL));

     for(i = 0; i < MaxC; i++) {

       for(j = 0; j < MaxL; j++) {

         do {
            r=(rand()%32);
         } while( c[r] > 258);
         ++c[r];
         n[i][j]=r;
         printf("%3d",n[i][j]);
         fprintf(fp,"%3d",n[i][j]);
       }

       printf("\n");
       fprintf(fp,"\n");

     }
     //free(n);
     fclose(fp);
     return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think the do/while loop is doing for you?

Comment: generating integers randomly between 0-31 and assigning the values to each element (256 x 256) in the 2d array  "n" and writing it to the .txt file defined above as "fp"

Comment: Why do you need the do/while for that? What is it doing that just assigning the results of `rand()%32` would not?

Comment: I am very new to C if you think there is a better way to do so, I'm happy to learn. Currently, this method does the job effectively for small 2d arrays but right now it's still running and taking > 20 minutes and still hasnt printed out the 256 x 256 array and stored it in the arrays256.txt file

Comment: Note that `r` is a number from 0 to 31. So at some point, **every** `c[r]` is greater than 258.

Comment: You wrote the code. I'm asking you to explain it. I see no need for 90% of your code so I'm wondering why it is there and if maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: It's there because I scrubbed it together while learning C and it was able to output what I needed for the small cases. Need this .txt file to input into my parallel programming code and haven't been able to generate the .txt file for over 20 minutes of execution.

Comment: How can you know that writing to the file takes forever when today is only September 29, 2018?

Comment: great point Eric!

Comment: As the answer below indicates, if you cannot explain what your code does then you shouldn't have that code in your program. If you don't know why you added the do/while loop you surely don't need it, unless you're programming by coincidence. https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence

Answer (score 2):

Consider the effects of:

```
do {
    r=(rand()%32);
} while( c[r] > 258);
++c[r];
```

This code is executed `MaxC*MaxL` times, due to the loops on `i` and `j`, which is 256•256 = 65,536 times. Each time, some `r` in the range 0 to 31 is chosen. The `while` loop excludes an `r` from being chosen if `c[r]` exceeds 258. This causes various `c[r]` to be incremented, with `r` ranging from 0 to 31.

Consider what happens when the loop has been executed 259•32 = 8,288 times. Then each of the 32 `c[r]` must have been incremented to 259. At that point, there is no `c[r]` left that does not satisfy `c[r] > 258`, so the `while` loop continues forever.

Comment: Thank you. that is very good explanation that breaks down the inefficiencies in the code. Do you have a recommendation on how I can achieve the same result more efficiently?

Comment: @YardenFeinberg: If you remove the lines `int c[257] = {0};`, `do {`, `} while( c[r] > 258);` and `++c[r];` (leaving in `r=(rand()%32);`), the program will complete quickly, assigning a number from 0 to 31 (inclusive) to each array element. However, I suspect the code involving the `c` array was intended to ensure some sort of even distribution for the random samples. In that case, additional code is needed. You would have to describe what you were attempting to achieve.

Comment: It will eventually end once one or more of the array values increments enough to be negative and that same index is chosen again. I wouldn't set my watch waiting though. :)

Comment: That was incredible help. that did exactly what i needed in a very quick execution. thank you man!

Comment: @RetiredNinja: No such increments are performed. Once all `c[r]` for `r` from 0 to 31 are incremented to 259, the loop with `while( c[r] > 258)` never exits, so no more increments are performed. There are no increments inside that loop.

Comment: You're right. I had convinced myself the increment was inside the innermost loop for some reason, perhaps hopefulness that it would eventually finish. :)